# Apply UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged to all textboxes wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How can I write template look like this?

```
    <DataTemplate ... TextBlock>
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged
    </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot change the default mode for the `UpdateSourceTrigger` in a style. This is configured as the `DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger` of the `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` class when the `DependencyProperty` (in this case the `Text` property) is registered.

You could either create a custom text box type which derives from `TextBox` and changes this value when registering the dependency property. Alternatively, you might want to look into the [Caliburn.Micro](https://caliburnmicro.com/) MVVM framework, which automatically sets this for all text boxes in an app (via code, as part of its convention based binding).

Comment: Have you had a look at using an MVVM framework? It will save you a whole host of work, and binding is a joy with Caliburn.Micro. If you wanted to roll your own solution, then maybe a custom markup extension could be written, or a custom binding, rather than creating your own TextBox derived type. Have a look at http://www.paulstovell.com/wpf-delaybinding or http://www.hardcodet.net/2008/04/wpf-custom-binding-class for some ideas.

Comment: This project has moved to github for v2.0
https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro

Answer (score 6):

Just extending accepted answer (and yes, i know i am necromancing this question :) ):

Actually, own TextBox is pretty simple, lets call it TextBoxExt (not much extended, but you know...)

```
public class TextBoxExt : TextBox
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo onTextPropertyChangedMethod 
      = typeof(TextBox).GetMethod("OnTextPropertyChanged", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    private static readonly MethodInfo coerceTextMethod 
      = typeof(TextBox).GetMethod("CoerceText", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    static TextBoxExt()
    {
      
      TextProperty.OverrideMetadata(
        typeof(TextBoxExt),

        // found this metadata with reflector:
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty,
                                      FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Journal,
                                      new PropertyChangedCallback(MyOnTextPropertyChanged),
                                      new CoerceValueCallback(MyCoerceText),
                                      true, // IsAnimationProhibited
                                      UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged)
        );
    }

    private static object MyCoerceText(DependencyObject d, object basevalue)
    {
      return coerceTextMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { d, basevalue });
    }

    private static void MyOnTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      onTextPropertyChangedMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { d, e });
    }

  }
```

and somewhere in your {ResourceDictionary}.xaml or in App.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type control:TextBoxExt}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}" />
```